# slick grid ensure data not getting called

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am using a slick grid with the following javascript. The problem is that the control never goes to ensureData(). Any ideas?

```
grid.onViewportChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    alert('1');
    var vp = grid.getViewport();
    alert('2');
    loader.ensureData(vp.top, vp.bottom);
    alert('3');
});

function ensureData(from, to) 
{          
    alert('55');
    var maxdata = Math.min(999, data.length);
    if (from < 0)
    from = 0;
    if (to > maxdata)
        to = maxdata;

    var fromPage = Math.floor(from / PAGESIZE);
    var toPage = Math.floor(to / PAGESIZE); // look-ahead

    while (fromPage <= toPage) {
        if (data[fromPage * PAGESIZE] == undefined) {
            data[fromPage * PAGESIZE] = null; // null indicates a 'requested but not available yet'

            var order = { "query": searchstr, "offset": (fromPage * PAGESIZE), "count": (((toPage - fromPage) * PAGESIZE) + PAGESIZE), "sort": sortcol, "order": ((sortdir > 0) ? "asc" : "desc") };
            req = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(order),

                url: "OrderService.svc/GetOrderList",

                success: onSuccess,
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (textStatus != 'abort')
                        onError(fromPage, toPage);
                }
            });
            onDataLoading.notify();
        }
        fromPage++;
    }
}
```

alert 1 is shown then
alert 2 is shown then
alert (error loading data) is shown & finally
alert 3 is shown....

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to fire on page load. As the name suggests, it fires when the viewport changes, i.e. when the user scrolls and the top and bottom visible rows in the viewport change.